# My service is restarted each time the application is closed

Tags: android, service, restart

I have a service in my app and start it as follows

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Prueba.class);
startService(intent);
```

Also, your method return onStartCommand STAR_STICKY;

However, every time I close the app the service is restarted. As for the service do not restarts and keep running?

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out may be this can be useful for you:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle